# PhpStorm update version text in .env file whenever a file is saved

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm to manage many of my client Laravel PHP projects, however as these projects have become larger it's become important to maintain and also show version information inside the system I'm developing.

To do this I'm using the `.env` file to hold a config called `APP_VERSION`.

What I would like to do is whenever a file is saved inside PhpStorm - any file - I want to automatically update the value (by incrementing) for this configuration variable.

However I can't seem to find a way to do this, or if it's even possible.

I have looked at File Watchers but this doesn't seem to solve the problem I'm having in that it only allows certain file types and even then it wants to run a compiler (such as a Sass or Less compiler, etc.) which is certainly not what I'm after.

Is there any way to do this, without me having to manually increment the minor version number with each file I update?

**Update**

So by using an adaptation of the answer by @LazyOne I created a small script which executes the necessary text update to the file in question.

I used a custom File Watcher which was setup against changes to any file type with a custom scope created to exclude certain files and folders that I didn't want watched.

End result, when I save a file that is within a valid scope, the script I wrote executes to update my file with the necessary change.

Comment: Could you please clarify "whenever a file is saved inside PhpStorm" - `.env` file saved? "any file - I want to automatically update the value" - which files? And what exactly update?

Comment: As per my question - whenever any file is saved, be it a php file, css file, html file, js file, etc. - I want to update the config value inside my .env file.

Comment: You should probably version manually and in a meaningful way. Try semver. http://semver.org/

Comment: While I appreciate the comment @ShaunUK your comment has nothing to do with the question I was asking.

Comment: @MatthewFritz I get the sense that you didn't appreciate the comment Matthew, but it is relevant. If you wanted an easy way to check if any files have changed you could take a hash of the project folder and increment your counter if that changes. Why do this for every change? You could do this in a pre-deployment script. Consider if .env is the right place for that version number, the version is a property of the code not the environment, so unless your code can bootstrap itself into different versions when it runs, it should probably be recorded somewhere else.

Comment: @ShaunUK while I appreciate your comment as being relevant to a discussion on the best practices of version control - this was something I was not asking. What I was asking was if there was a way to simply change a text value - any value in this case, not necessarily a version number - inside a text file, again not necessarily an .env file - automatically when any file get's saved inside PhpStorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhpStorm does not have such functionality (including other IDEA-based IDEs). There are some tickets asking for such functionality .. but it will definitely not work for your scenario (the use case there is different).

You will have to do it "manually". By this I mean:

- either actual manually editing the file (as in your question)...
- or automate it by writing some script (e.g. in PHP) that would do it for you and then just execute it either on demand (e.g. External Tools or manually) or via File Watcher (File Watcher is basically (simply speaking) External Tools that is run on file modification -- you can run any program there, even your own shell/batch script).

Such script will  open your `.env` file, find the right line and edit the value there -- little bit of file parsing job -- nothing super heavy.

Hint: Laravel has `artisan` .. and one of the commands is `key:generate` (which alters `.env` file -- at very least it is run at very least once when you create new Laravel app). You may do it in similar fashion -- do your script as artisan command (so that you have full Laravel power behind it) and just call it when needed (File Watcher or whatever).

---

**P.S.** Instead of editing `.env` file (which is more environment specific rather than global setting, which version info is) .. why not store this in **custom config file** (e.g. `config/version.php`) which **will contain that info only** and therefore will be much easier to alter or even generate from scratch (template) as it has much simple structure and therefore no need to maintain other existing info there (which you have to do with `.env` files)?

At the end of the day -- there is no big difference for you/programmers between calling `env('APP_VERSION')` and `config('version.app_version')` to get that info in your app.

Comment: This type of functionality would certainly be well received, at least by me, so I'll add my request to any existing tickets I find on the matter. As far as Laravel artisan is concerned this may well facilitate my requirement when done alongside a custom File Watcher template. I'll look into this and revert back if this solves my need.

Comment: **P.S.** Instead of editing `.env` file (which is more environment specific rather than global setting, which version info is) .. why not edit **custom config file** (e.g. `version.php`) which will contain only that info and therefore will be much easier to alter or even generate from scratch/template as it has much simple structure and no need to maintain other existing info there (which you have to do with `.env` files)? At the end of the day -- there is no big difference between `env('APP_VERSION')` and `config('version.app_version')` to get that info in your app.

Comment: Certainly a better approach as far as the location for this (and some other global settings I've created). Does a new config file need to be declared anywhere, or is the mere existence of the file enough for the configurations included within to be valid within the application?

Comment: About tickets -- they mostly ask "automatically update date/time info in currently edited file before it gets saved (based on some marker/regex)" -- they not asking "update some another file with some info when current file gets modified" -- that's the difference between their and your case. An example of such ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7178

Comment: Just check how `config()` works (it's Laravel function). 1) Config files are stored in `PROJECT_ROOT/config` folder .. and they are simple `.php` files that return an array; 2) In `config('version.app_version')` you are telling to look for `app_version` array key in `config/version.php` file. You can also provide default value in case if no such file/key defined there. Not sure what else to clarify here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's possible directly within PHPStorm. You could, however, write yourself a small PHP script which monitors the specified directory for file changes and when one happens your script can make the necessary changes in the file you want.

Try looking at [inotify](http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php) for more info.

Comment: > This extension is considered unmaintained and dead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I've corrected it with inotify, which seems to be more up-to-date. I'm not using this feature however so if somebody knows even better ways feel free to add your answer :)

Comment: [It doesn't work on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/inotify.requirements.php). It *could* work on macOS though. (There is no indication in the question of the used OS.)

Comment: My development environment is on Windows however my production and staging environments are using linux so this may be an option which I will look into. I have my PHPStorm setup to automatically upload any changed file up to my linux staging environment so running inotify on my staging environment may be the answer I'm looking for. I'll revert back if this solves my need.